# Load table session return null in controller

Tags: extensions, joomla-4.x

In a controller of my component in Joomla! 4.1 i want to load the table session but it return null :

```
$table = Table::getInstance('session', 'JTable');
$table->load($session->getId());
$table->username = $this->user->username;
$table->store();
```

How to load table session ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no table class for session table. You can create it yourself or run queries manually against `#__session` table.